# Needing example to load jqplot with multiple series, date-based data from json file

Tags: jqplot

Been searching and cannot find exactly what I am looking for. Need to load multiple series into one jqplot, with each series coming from its own data file.

The example here http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php does show how to load a series from a file, but when I convert file to have date data, then it stops working, probably just a formatting issue, but cannot solve. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the data in the txt file:
[["7/11/2011 04:00:00am",85.0],["7/12/2011 04:00:00AM",87.4],["7/13/2011 04:00:00AM",90.0]]

Here is the code:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
    var line = [ ];
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
        // have to use synchronous here, else returns before data is fetched
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            ret = data;
        }
    });
    return ret;
};

var jsonurl = "./jsondata1.txt";

plo12 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          tickInterval: '1 day',
          tickOptions:{formatString:'%y/%m/%d'}
      }
  }
});
});</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `dataRendererOptions` parameter to declare possible files, like this:

```
plo12 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {file1:'name_of_file_1', file2:'name_of_file2'}
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
```

Next use for-each to iterate trough the dataRendererOptions - Object:

```
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot,op) {
    var ret = null;
$.each(op,function(i,n) {
    $.ajax({
        // have to use synchronous here, else returns before data is fetched
        async: false,
        url: url+'/'+i,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            ret[]= data;
        }
    }); //end ajax
 });//end each
return ret;
}
```

This code is not testet, but the idea behind could fit your needs.

Comment: So if I understand `dataRendererOptions` object will be accessible inside the `ajaxDataRenderer` method under the `op` variable? If that is how it works then (+1). BTW can you please link me to an explanation saying what exactly this weird (i.e. first time seen) notation means: `ret[] = data;`?

Comment: @Boro `ret[] = data;` <- thats a year ago, hard question! ;-) well: if i remember right, this means: define `ret` as an `array` / `object` and assign/append `data` as one (new) Element

Comment: Thanks you, The Bndr, for replaying. So if I understand right it is equivalent of this notation: `ret = [data];`, right?